# odoo domain using employee information

Tags: python, xml, odoo

I have 2 models: `Plan` and `Employee`

```py
class Plan(models.Model):
   _name="plan"
   subject_id=fields.Many2one("subject")
   name=fields.Char('name')
   teacher_id=fields.Many2one('hr.employee')

class Employee(models.Model):
   _inherit="hr.employee"
   subject_ids=fields.Many2many("subject")

class Subject(models.Model):
   _name="subject"
   name=fields.Char("Subject Name")
```

Since each `Employee` has its own user, I need to create a domain that allows me to show plans of subjects that are asigned to the `Employee` corresponding to the current user.

Here is my xml.

```xml
        <record id="action_open_didactic_unit_plan" model="ir.actions.act_window">
          <field name="name">Plan</field>
          <field name="type">ir.actions.act_window</field>
          <field name="res_model">plan</field>
          <field name="view_type">form</field>
          <field name="view_mode">tree,form</field> 
          <field name="domain">[('teacher_id.user_id.id','=',uid)]</field>
```

At this moment im filtering only plans asigned to teacher_id with current user id.  but I need to show also plans created in all subjects asigned to teacher.

I was thinking in some thing like this.

```
('subject_id', 'in', [teacher_list_of_subjects])
```

Comment: More details, and to get the current user in odoo 10 `self.env.user`

Comment: Where do you want to filter records? On a menu action? In code anywhere? On a search filter? In Record Rules? Please describe your requirement in more detail.

Comment: Thanks... question is edited... I need a domain  in my xml.